# bcp holding the csv file forever and not writing anything from the table back to the CSV when called from c#.net website

Tags: c#, file, csv, stored-procedures, bcp

"DBNAME" represents - server name
The following is sql statement

```
set @sql = 'bcp xxxxx.dbo.CsvTemp out D:/EDI/INCOMING/test1.csv  -c -t, -T -SDBNAME'
```

which is part of a stored procedure "SP1".
When i call this "SP1" from .net website. BCP utility just creates the file at the location , does not write anything to it and holds the file forever. 
when i run it from SQL management server. It works fine.

Really stuck.
don't know what to do.
Thanks
Shweta

Comment: Why do you need to do this at the sql level?

Comment: can you be more specific about how you run it by hand (not from .net website). do you use "SQL Server Management Studio", open a new connection/query window and just call the SP1? At first glance I would lean toward your value for "DBNAME" not being what you think it is. Can you confirm (check variable values, double check) that both calls are using the same server?

Comment: also, how is the bcp command executed from within the proc? xp_cmdshell?